# Why does is_array() leak memory in PHP?

Tags: php

According to my xdebug output, is_array() leaks the amount of memory that gets passed to it as an argument. If I pass it a large array, it leaks a ton of memory just in order to check if it's an array.

Is there a workaround for this?

```
   17.4313   21858520   +70004                   -> is_array() [...]/app/app_model.php:526
```

Here's the code snippet that causes the leak:

```
        $ret = $this->behaviors[$b[$i]]->afterFind($this, $results, true);
        if (is_array($ret)) {
            $results = $ret;
        }
```

I'm running this on Linux (Ubuntu 9.04)

PHP: 5.3.2

xdebug: 2.0.5

uname -a gives me this:

Linux linux8 2.6.28-19-server #64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 18 21:57:33 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: I think you forgot to specify PHP version and your code, which should be relevant to this leak. `insertPHPJoke()`

Comment: What do you mean "leak memory"? The memory is not reclaimed after the call?

Comment: Is I cannot reproduce it here: have you got `xdebug.collect_params` enabled, and what happens if you disable it?

Comment: After checking: no, collect params doesn't seem the culprit, and I cannot reproduce it. Some version numbers (PHP & xdebug), OS & a specific test script could be required.

Comment: Just look in the source code if you want to know what happens: [type.c:201 PHP 5.3.2](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/type.c?revision=295794&view=markup#l201)

Comment: PHP 5.3.2 / XDebug 2.1.0 / kernel 2.6.32 I have no problems (Debian). Of course, I cannot run your snippet, so I only have the problem with an arbitrary large array. However, you might want to try to disable xdebug altogether & check `memory_get_(peak_)usage()` to check wether it's xdebug itself which is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first reaction:

[Select isn't broken](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips).

My second reaction:

You can conclude three things:

- a widely spread piece of software (`is_array`) is broken - You are the first one to notice
- xdebug is broken reports a leak where there is none
- xdebug and PHP don't work together nicely as it concerns memory management

A widely spread and used function is most often not the problem.  Try to narrow down the occurence of the 'xdebug leak report' by running simpler code:

```
$arr = array_fill( 0, 10000, "content" );
$mallocbytes=true;// set to true to get process 
$usage=memory_get_usage(!$mallocbytes);
for( $i=0; $i!=1000000; $i=$i+1) { 
   is_array($arr); 
   $newusage=memory_get_usage(!$mallocbytes);
   if( $newusage != $usage ) {
      print( "diff after $i'th is_array: ".($newusage-$usage)."\n" );
   }
   $usage=$newusage;
}
```

Take a look at the actual memory consumption of your PHP runtime.  I bet it won't grow.

Comment: After running your example, I believe that the problem is in xdebug and not in the PHP runtime.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php may be a suitable work-around. The best path is to submit a patch that fixes the bug, but that may be outside the scope of your contract.